# How can I recover program.vb{Design] pane after renaming Form1?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer

My vb.net program was functioning properly.  After I renamed Form1 in the code pane of Visual Studio 2015 the Program.vb[Design] pane will not open and the following message appears:

> The class Form1 can be designed, but is not the first class in the file. Visual Studio requires that designers use the first class in the file. Move the class code so that it is the first class in the file and try loading the designer again.

The name change was in the first class (form) so I cannot move it further up.

Before the change there were no errors.  After the change there are many handles clause, variable not declared and not a member of errors.

I had 2 choices for Startup form in the Application tab of My Project before the change.  After I have only 1 choice from a dropdown list.  Both choices were Class names.

Is there anything I can do to recover the Designer view?  Should I just recreate the form?

Thanks in advance, for any suggestions.

Comment: ` I renamed Form1 in the code pane` change the name back, to undo the error.  Then use the property oane to change the name.  The IDE will change the name everywhere properly

Comment: ...the form code you normally edit is a **Partial** class which means there is another class file where all the designer generated code goes.  There all the controls are declared and initialized for instance.  When you change a name of something via the Property pane, the IDE changes those accordingly.

Comment: You have to do it the right way, the form name is used in multiple places.  Rename it back so your code compiles again.  Then right-click the name and choose Rename.